# Insert Into Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a small issue with some coding of mine. For some reason my entries aren't dropping in my DB. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code...

```
<?php 
    $dbhost="localhost"; 
    $dbname="DBNAME"; 
    $dbuser="USER"; 
    $dbpasswd="PASSWORD"; // connect to the db 

    $dbcxn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd); 
    if (!$dbcxn) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 

    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($dbcxn, $dbname); 
    if (!$db_selected) { 
        die ('Can\'t use dbreviews : ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 

    $query = "INSERT INTO entries ( submitterFirstName, submitterLastName, submitterPhone, submitterEmail, referredFirstName, referredLastName, referredPhone, referredEmail, referredReason)
      VALUES ('$submitterFirstName', '$submitterLastName', '$submitterPhone', '$submitterEmail', '$referredFirstName', '$referredLastName', '$referredPhone', '$referredEmail', '$referredProject')";

    $result=mysqli_query($dbcxn, $query);
```

?>

Comment: 1. What does mysqli_error() tell you? 2. You're wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: The structure of your entries table will also help

Comment: Im not getting any error msgs. My entries just aren't dropping.

Comment: You're not getting any error messages, because you're not checking for errors. And like @Sebas says, you should echo the contents of $query, and post it here too.

Comment: was autocommit disable?  if so you will need to do a commit to get the data to be inserted into the db.  make sure you have insert priv to the table of the db you are inserting into.  can you post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to check is echo the query back to yourself and read it over.

Second, check the table structure. Make sure the column names are all spelled correctly and that all fields exist in your table (I've accidently forgotten to add a column before).

Third, you may or may not receive error messages depending on your configuration. But, you can manually check.

```
if (!$result) {
  echo mysqli_error($dbcxn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query variable to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO entries " .
 "( submitterFirstName, submitterLastName, submitterPhone, submitterEmail, referredFirstName, " .
 " referredLastName, referredPhone, referredEmail, referredReason )" .
 " VALUES ('" .
    $submitterFirstName . "', '" .
    $submitterLastName  . "', '" .
    $submitterPhone     . "', '" .
    $submitterEmail     . "', '" .
    $referredFirstName  . "', '" .
    $referredLastName   . "', '" .
    $referredPhone      . "', '" .
    $referredEmail      . "', '" .
    $referredProject    . "')";
```

and it should be working.

Suggesting to use [***mysqli prepare***](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: @KarlSmith OK. Some typo errors corrected. Please try with the change proposed.

Comment: ok...I tried the proposed changed and got no errors..but my entries still aren't going into my db!!

Comment: @KarlSmith Two cases: 1. Insert privileges. But, as you said, you got no errors, this may not be the error. 2. Auto commit state. After query execution make a call to `mysqli->commit()`

Answer (score 0):

First thing first should be code formatting, it will help you read the code and consequently find your errors easier.

```
$query = "

INSERT INTO 
    entries 
    (
    submitterFirstName, 
    submitterLastName, 
    submitterPhone,        
    submitterEmail, 
    referredFirstName, 
    " . 
       "referredLastName, 
    referredPhone, 
    referredEmail, 
    referredReason
    )
        " .
    " VALUES 
    (
    '$submitterFirstName', 
    '$submitterLastName', 
    '$submitterPhone', 
    '    $submitterEmail', 
    '$referredFirstName'," .
    "'$referredLastName', 
    '$referredPhone', 
    '$referredEmail',    
    '$referredProject'
    );
"
```

The above is your query string split onto several lines, there are some errors which should be evident straight away?  Once formatted I would do `echo $query` and view the output of $query.

Also try seeing if you can do an insert without using php (using mysql workbench, php admin etc) then compare it with the string value you have set as $query.

```
// less errors, please note that inside "" you can include php $vars without needing to escape.  

$query = "

INSERT INTO 
    entries 
    (
    submitterFirstName, 
    submitterLastName, 
    submitterPhone,        
    submitterEmail, 
    referredFirstName, 
    referredLastName, 
    referredPhone, 
    referredEmail, 
    referredReason
    )
 VALUES 
    (
    '$submitterFirstName', 
    '$submitterLastName', 
    '$submitterPhone', 
    '$submitterEmail', 
    '$referredFirstName',
    '$referredLastName', 
    '$referredPhone', 
    '$referredEmail',    
    '$referredProject'
    );
";
```